# Why does one of the paddings in my code not work

Tags: html

padding-right doesn't work but padding-left does. I tried putting padding in other places, but it didn't work. Just started to learn, please guide me. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/iorre/L49w7bxa/2/

```css
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.header-background {
    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}


header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;

}
```

```html
    <body>
        <header>

            <h1 class='header-background header-text'>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        </header>

    </body>
```

Comment: What makes you feel the padding is not working? The padding is 'inside' the black background and is the same on both ends. What you might be looking for is margin. Try for instance to add `margin: 0px auto`.

Comment: Pudding work, I can see its boundaries on the element code, but it does not limit the header on the right side. `margin: 0px auto`
didn't help when I put it in `header` or `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if this helps
https://jsfiddle.net/dLj5utz2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Project number 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <h1 class='header-background header-text'>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
</header>
<p style="position: relative; top: 2000px; margin-top: 60px;">qweqdas</p>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>


body {
background-color: whitesmoke;
margin: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
padding-left: 0 auto;

}

.header-background {
background-color: black;
background-size: cover;
height: 70px;
margin: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}

.header-text {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
 }


 header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;



 }
```

Comment: @iorre please upvote, if you are satisfied with the answer

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I want the distance from the page borders to be the same with paddings, but your method doesn't have indentation. I'm sorry I didn't phrase the question correctly.

Comment: If you want the black background not touch the sides, you can change the `auto` in the margin to `100px` in the above fiddle..